# how can i compare two arrays in Javascript by using binarysearch?

Tags: javascript

How can i use a binary search to compare two arrays and count the number of times it matched, i did find some here where one item was compared to an array..follwing is regular one for example ..thanx for the help.

```js
var a = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"];
var b = ["8", "1", "3", "9", "4", "6", "8"];
var count = 0;

for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
        if (a[i] == b[j]) count += 1;
    }
}

document.write(count);
```

I tried to do this ..

```js
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var left = 0;
    var right = b.length - 1;
    while (left <= right) {
        var mid = parseInt((left + right) / 2);
        if (b[mid] == a[i]) {
            count += 1;
        } else if (b[mid] < a[i]) {
            left = mid + 1;
        }
        else {
            right = mid - 1;
        }
    }
}

document.write(count);
```

Comment: _"count the number of times it matched"_ - The number of times _what_ matched? Do you mean count the number of elements in one array that are also in a second array? Your example array `b` happens to have the same element twice (`"8"`) - should that be counted as matching twice (if it was in array `a`)?

Comment: is this homework, because if it isn't there are easier ways to do this.

Comment: binary search is not meant for comparisons - in order to compare you'd have to match each entry on both arrays, which is a behavior not implemented by this algorithm.

Comment: @ Peter Wooster so what is the best way to compare 2 large arrays considering about 4000 elements..to count the number of element in one array tht is also in second array? thanx

Comment: @ nnnnnn just the number of elements to the second array ..two 8's in b was a mistake .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linearly go through the `b` array and use a binary search of the `a` array.

```
function binarySearch(a, value) {
    var left = 0;
    var right = a.length - 1;
    while (left <= right) {
        var mid = (left + right) >> 1;
        if (a[mid] === value) {
            return mid;
        } else if (a[mid] < value) {
            left = mid + 1;
        }
        else {
            right = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}


var a = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"];
var b = ["8", "1", "3", "9", "4", "6", "8"];
var count = 0;
b.forEach(function(value) { if (binarySearch(a, value) >= 0) ++count; });
```

Comment: only one array needs to be sorted. If both are sorted you can compare them linearly by merging.

Comment: @PeterWooster - Yeah, I just realized that after hitting the post button.

Comment: @PeterWooster - Now for something completely different.